# Why we don't use the universal quantifier in the usual definition of the cartesian product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I see everywhere that the usual definition of a cartesian product between two set is :

$$\mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B} = \{(a,b): a \in \mathrm{A}, b \in \mathrm{B} \}$$

I wondered why we don't add a universal quantifier like so :
$$\mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B} = \{(a,b): \forall a \in \mathrm{A}, \forall b \in \mathrm{B} \}$$
Asking myself this question led me to the following reflection :

I know that a set-builder notation is of the form :
$$   \{x: \Phi (x)\}$$ where :

- $\Phi (x)$ is a logical predicate such that **all values** of x for which the predicate holds belongs to the set being defined
- I do think $x$ is what we call "an unbound variable" in logic
- Hence $\{x: \Phi (x)\}$ can be interpreted as "all mathematical objects for which the predicate holds belongs to the set being defined"

Therefore, the notation :
$$\mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B} = \{(a,b): a \in \mathrm{A}, b \in \mathrm{B} \}$$
can be interpreted as : "all ordered pair for which it's first element is in $\mathrm{A}$ and it's second is in $\mathrm{B}$ belongs to the cartesian product of those sets (which is a set)".

So in the notation where I add the universal quantifier, I made a grammatical mistake, because "for all" is not to be added with the usage of a free variable), my question was why (when I didn't know the existence of "unbound variable") we don't have to put a universal quantifier this way :
$$\mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B} = \{\forall(a,b): a \in \mathrm{A}, b \in \mathrm{B} \}$$
After all, a quantifier ("$\exists$") is used in the correct definition, so why can't we use an other?
I'm pretty sure it is related to bond and free variables : if one choose the last definition I wrote, one makes the variable $(a,b)$ bounded, if one choose the usual definition, one use a free variable, therefore if the last definition I wrote is wrong, it might be because we can't use bounded variable in the set builder notation (outside the predicate), isn't it?

If it the case, why?

Does the formula "$\mathrm{A} \times \mathrm{B} = \{(a,b): a \in \mathrm{A}, b \in \mathrm{B} \}$" belongs to first-order logic or Higher-order logic (I'm a beginner in formal logic)?

Thank you

Comment: The actual way you would formally define it as $$\Bigl\{x \,\Bigm|\, \exists a\exists b\bigl(a\in A\wedge b\in B\wedge x=(a,b)\bigr)\Bigr\}.$$ So that $\Phi(x)$ is the formula $\exists a\exists b(a\in A\wedge b\in B\wedge x=(a,b)\}$. But this is unwieldly, so one uses the informal shorthand $\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Comment: $A\times B=\{(a,b):\forall a\in A, \forall b\in B\}$ has just no sense...

Comment: To follow-up on the comment by @Surb note that $\forall a\in A$ is like saying "negation" with nothing afterwards. In order to make sense you have to specify what statement the logical operation $\forall a\in A$ (or the logical operation "negation") is being applied to.

Comment: Because the set-builder acts as a quantifier: it binds the variable. In the formula $\Phi(x)$ of $\{ x \mid \Phi(x) \}$, the variable $x$ must be free.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so the set-builder gives us two particular informations thanks to $\{ · \}$ : 
- it makes a set from the inside variable
- this variable in the formula $\Phi(x)$ (so before $\{ · \}$ acts) is free, but the ''function" $\Phi$ bounds it : we could read $\{ x | \ \Phi(x) \}$ as : $\Phi(x)$ is a an image of a "function" which maps x to true

Then "$\forall x | \ \Phi(x) $"  tells us : "we consider all $x$ which are map to true, but "consider" has not the axioms of a set so we write $\{ x | \ \Phi(x) \}$ to say "we collect all $x$ which are true under $\Phi$, they make a set"?

Comment: The set-builder produce a *term* (the name of a set) from a formula. Thus, its meaning is: "the set of all and only those objects that satisfy the "condition" expressed by the formula"

Comment: Thank you all, and especially @MauroALLEGRANZA, you made it easy